# Coordinate transformation in OpenCV

Tags: opencv, coordinate-transformation

I have a polyline figure, given as an array of relative `x` and `y` point coordinates (0.0 to 1.0).

I have to draw the figure with random position, scale and rotation angle.

How can I do it in the best way?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a simple transformation with RT matrix.

Let `X = (x y 1)^t` be coordinates of one point of your figure. Let `R` be a 2x2 [rotation matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix), and `T` be 2x1 translation vector of the transformation You plan to make. RT matrix `A` will have the form of `A = [R T;0 0 1]`. To get transformed coordinates of point X, You need to do this simple calculation `AX = X'`, where `X'` are the new coordinates. Now, to get the whole figure transformed, instead of using a single column, You use a matrix where each column has `x` coordinate in first row, `y` in the second and `1` in the third row.

Of course You can try to use functions provided by OpenCV, shown in [this tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/warp_affine/warp_affine.html#warp-affine), or ones intended for vectors of points instead of whole images, but the way above makes You actually understand what are You doing ;)